# Swift transform dictionary into array using properties of object

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a dictionary with objects that contains array. For example let's sat each object Factory has object manager `factory.manager`.

Dictionary:

```
["key1": factory1]
["key2": factory2]
["key3": factory3]
```

I need to get all managers by transforming dictionary to an array:

```
[factory1.manager, factory2.manager, factory3.manager]
```

How can I do it using `map` for example by avoiding using for cycle.

Comment: Array(dictionary.values.map{$0.manager})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create an Array of those values:

```
   Array(dictionary.values.map{$0.manager})
```

assuming the dictionary instance is of type `[String:Factory]`

Comment: hey dude, thanks) one more question can I do it for getting Set?

Comment: yea it really returns what I mention )

Comment: you sound surprised :)

Comment: a set can be created: `Set(dictionary.values.map{$0.manager})`

Comment: cannot invoke initializer Set<>

Comment: instances in a `Set` must be from a type that is `Hashable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106730/discussion-between-matrosov-alexander-and-sketchytech).

Answer (score -1):

```
class Factory{

    var manager:String = ""

}

var myFactoryDict = ["key1":Factory(),"key2":Factory(),"key3":Factory()]

myFactoryDict.values.map { (factoryObj:Factory) -> String in

    return factoryObj.manager
}
```